# how to add coupons Limit to a single customer do not use multiple coupon on same cart

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, coupon, coupon-codes

how to set rule for customer so he do not use multiple coupon on same cart.

Customer can apply only one coupon code at a time. I dont want to give access to use another coupon code. (You can use only one coupon code).

Comment: once coupon code applies and amount deducted from subtotal, after that you can hide/remove "Apply Discount Code" block from checkout and cart page and just display a message whatever you want to display.